# Treeview not working in C# asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm trying to build a tree view of files and folders from a folder (called ***Folders***) in my root directory.

My c# code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public class Default2: Seisan.DefaultTemplate
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!this.IsPostBack){
        DirectoryInfo rootInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Folders/"));
        this.PopulateTreeView(rootInfo, null);
    }
}

private void PopulateTreeView(DirectoryInfo dirInfo, TreeNode treeNode)
{
foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
{
    TreeNode directoryNode = new TreeNode(directory.Name, directory.FullName);

    if (treeNode == null)
    {
        TreeView.Nodes.Add(directoryNode);
    }
    else
    {
        treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(directoryNode);
    }

    //Get all files in the Directory.
    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.FullName, "_blank", (new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/"))).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file.FullName)).ToString());
        directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(fileNode);
    }

    PopulateTreeView(directory, directoryNode);
    }
}
```

and my asp.Net code for the tree view is:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView" runat="server" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" NodeIndent="15">
    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
        <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="2px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px"></NodeStyle>
                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
        <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                    VerticalPadding="0px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

I'm getting this error when running:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.Nodes.get'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 43:         {
>
> Line 44:             **TreeView.Nodes.Add(directoryNode);**
>
> Line 45:         }
>
> Line 46:         else

Treeview is declared in the asp.Net form though. I don't know what is wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to create a root node and start adding nodes to it. Line 44 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Line 44 should add the root node to the TreeView. and then comes the else statements for the child nodes.

Comment: TreeView in your code is the name of the class, not the name of your TreeView instance. Poor choice to name your treeview control. Call it MyTreeView or something.

Comment: I renamed and instantiated it but now no folders are showing. The page is loading with nothing! Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Do you have any files in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.MapPath("~/Folders/")
```

will look for a folder called Folders **inside the ASP.NET Project**:

[image: Folders folder inside the web application project]

All I did was to make sure I have this folder in my project with a couple of sub folders and it's working just fine:

**Output in the browser:**

[image: ASP.NET TreeView control]